# How can I use SUMIF to sum based on date?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I was trying to use the `=SUMIF` function to calculate the expected expenses to date. In other words, only values in the `Amount` column should be added to the total if the respective value in the `Date` column is less than the value labelled `Today's Date`.

Your help is appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

The following formula should produce the result you desire:

```
=SUMIF(D5:D13,"<="&D2,F5:F13)
```

### Explanation

The issue was that you did not have an ampersand between `"<="` and `D2`. The second argument of a `=SUMIF` must be a string, but Google Sheets does not know to interpret the value in `D2` as a string by default. Thus, you get a formula parse error. By concatenating `D2` with `<=` as a string, the `=SUMIF`'s second argument will now be a single string and the formula will function correctly.

Functions used:

- [=SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en)